Laravel filament: Is it possible to get next record id while creating a record?
I want to save an image and I want to save it in below directory.
sliders/<slider_id>/SFLKSJFDE234223512.jpg
Here is my filament form code
 Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image_path')
            ->label('Image')
            ->moveFiles()
            ->image()
            ->directory(function (Slider $slider, string $operation) {
                if ($operation === 'create') {
                    $totalSliders = Slider::count() + 1;
                    return "sliders/{$totalSliders}";
                }

                return "sliders/{$slider->id}";
            })
            ->required(),

This works until I delete any record. After deleting, If I create a new record, the directory name doesn't get the proper ID. I want to keep the record id in the directory string.
Any help would be really appreciating.

You can use spatie media library package for the same.
they will create folder structure which you are looking for...

https://filamentphp.com/plugins/filament-spatie-media-library
